# My filter of my list doesnt hide everything

Tags: javascript, jquery

Helly guys, again, I have a small question about a little problem I have. I have a website, where you can create recipes and all of the created recipes are shown on one site. Of course you want to filter this list by the recipe-name, so I built a little search-box, but this box doenst work 100% perfect.
When I want to filter the first element, everything works but when I want to filter some of the lower recipes, the filter-function itself works, but beside the search box, there is still one of the subscribe-buttons, which belongs to a hided recipe.

Here are three pictures, which will hopefully describe my problem a little bit more visually:

[image: all recipes]

---

[image: filtered the first recipe]

---

[image: filtered a recipe in the middle]

The first code is the jquery and the second one is my html (.ejs) with the list

```
$(document).ready(function(){
        $("#myInput").on("keyup", function() {
            var value = $(this).val().toLowerCase();
            $("#myList #recipe_name").filter(function() {
                $(this).toggle($(this).text().toLowerCase().indexOf(value) > -1)
            });
        });
    });
```

---

```
<input id="myInput" type="text" placeholder="Search..">
    <% for(var i=0; i < recipe.length; i++) {  %>

    <div id="myList">
        <div id="recipe_name"><%=recipe[i].titel%></div>
        <div id="subscribe_button"><button type="submit" class="button_subscribe" value="<%=recipe[i]._id%> <%=recipe[i].titel%> <%=recipe[i].ingredients%>  <%=recipe[i].discreption%> <%=recipe[i].theme%> <%=recipe[i].difficulty%>"  id="button_small" onclick="this.innerHTML='Subscribed'">Subscribe</button></div>
    </div>
            <% } %>
```

Comment: Your loop is repeating the same `id` attributes multiple times which is invalid HTML. Change the `id` to `class`.

Comment: Which id's should I change to classes?

Comment: All of them in the `for` loop

Comment: It is still not working :/

Comment: Did you change the jQuery selectors too?

Comment: The problem wasnt the classes or ids. I fixed the problem, by putting another div around the recipe_name and the subscribe_button to join them into one div. Now everything works great! But thank you Rory! :)